# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in $httpInterceptor

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http-interceptors

I want to send a default data parameter for all the $http requests in my app.
I referred to this answer [$httpInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114950/add-common-parameter-in-each-http-request). I can able to set default headers, but for parameters its not working. I understood that i want to send an array to push to a Json object and I tried this.

```
angular
    .module('app.main')
    .factory('myHttpInterceptor', myHttpInterceptor);

myHttpInterceptor.$inject = ['Constant'];

function myHttpInterceptor(Constant) {
    var data = [{'foo': 'fooBar'}];
    return {
        request: requestInterceptor
    };

    function requestInterceptor(config) {
        config.params.push(data);
        return config;
    }
}
```

In my app.module I specified this

```
app.config([...,'$httpProvider'...){
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}
```

Then error comes in config.params.push

I want to send a default parameter like

> foo: fooBar

for all my http requests, thank you

Comment: Angular version ? Since this `$httpProvider.interceptors` was added in 1.1.4 .

Comment: There are not always `params` in the request, only if you add them yourself in the request

Comment: angularjs version is 1.4.4

Comment: ok, it is sending params to all .html files too, i want to send them as form-data, and to only $http API requests,any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have the params array present at the time you push. try this code.

Initialize `config.params array`, if it is not present.Then push it.

```
angular
    .module('app.main')
    .factory('myHttpInterceptor', myHttpInterceptor);

myHttpInterceptor.$inject = ['Constant'];

function myHttpInterceptor(Constant) {
    var data = [{'foo': 'fooBar'}];
    return {
        request: requestInterceptor
    };

    function requestInterceptor(config) {
        if(config.params.length != 0)
        {
            config.params.push(data);
        }
        else
        {
            config.params = []
            config.params.push(data);
        }
        return config;
    }
}
```

**This pushes to the params if present, or creates new params**

This should solve your issue.

Comment: sorry for the delay, im getting

Comment: config.params.push is not a function

Comment: `if(config.params.length != 0)`, pls check now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array if it's undefined.

```
function myHttpInterceptor(Constant) {
    var data = [{'foo': 'fooBar'}];
    return {
        request: requestInterceptor
    };

    function requestInterceptor(config) {
        config.params = config.params || [];
        config.params.push(data);
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: @KarthikGirraj it means that config.params already exists and isn't an array. Try to set new config property if your not sure whether to use config.params.